# Grunt BrowserSync and SASS watch

Tags: sass, gruntjs, browser-sync

I am having some issues setting up BrowserSync with a watch task for SASS processing.

When I execute:

```
grunt
```

The BrowserSync server starts and I see "Serving files from: ./ and Watching files. The sass is never compiled. It's like both tasks aren't being initiated.

When I execute:

```
grunt watch
```

The sass is watch and compiled correctly, but no BrowserSync server is started.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        files: 'components/css/scss/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
    },

    sass: {                              // Task
        dist: {                            // Target
          options: {                       // Target options
            style: 'expanded'
          },
          files: {                         // Dictionary of files
            'components/css/screen.css' : 'components/css/scss/screen.scss'        // 'destination': 'source'
          }
        }
    },

    browserSync: {
        bsFiles: {
            src : ['components/css/*.css', '*.html']
        },
        options: {
            server: {
                baseDir: "./"
            },
            options: {
                watchTask: true
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

grunt.registerTask('default', ["browserSync", "watch"]);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this fixes the error:

```
    browserSync: {
        bsFiles: {
            src : ['components/css/*.css', '*.html']
        },
        options: {
            server: {
                baseDir: "./"
            },
            watchTask: true
        }
    }
```

You have an error with watchTask option.